# Enhanced dependencies annotator: conjoined verbs?

Tags: stanford-nlp

In their paper "Enhanced English Universal Dependencies:
An Improved Representation for Natural Language Understanding Tasks", Schuster & Manning state that "In the case of conjoined verbs, the arguments of the first verb, e.g., the subject and the direct object, also become the arguments of the other verbs." (pg 2, http://nlp.stanford.edu/pubs/schuster2016enhanced.pdf).

However, when I run their example "the store buys and sells cameras" through the parse annotator with default options, it misses `dobj(sells, cameras)`. Any ideas why?

Here is are the enhanced dependencies returned. I'm using CoreNLP v 3.7, parse annotator, `EnhancedPlusPlusDependenciesAnnotation`. Partial code is below. I have tried *depparse* with the same result.

```
root(ROOT-0, buys-3)
det(store-2, the-1)
nsubj(buys-3, store-2)
nsubj(sells-5, store-2)
cc(buys-3, and-4)
conj:and(buys-3, sells-5)
dobj(buys-3, cameras-6)



props.put("annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,parse,regexner");
...
System.out.println(sent.get(SemanticGraphCoreAnnotations.EnhancedPlusPlusDependenciesAnnotation.class).toString(SemanticGraph.OutputFormat.LIST));
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't do anything wrong, this is a known limitation of the deterministic converter.

From section 4.2 of the paper:

> Our converter generates enhanced and enhanced++ dependency
>   graphs as described in the previous sections, with one
>   exception. Currently, we don’t propagate object or nominal
>   modifier relations in clauses with conjoined verb phrases
>   such as “the store buys and sells cameras”. The reason for
>   this is that there are also many cases such as “she was reading
>   or watching a movie” where it would be wrong to add
>   these relations and there are no syntactic cues that would
>   allow us to distinguish these cases.

Comment: Thanks for explaining, I missed that caveat.